# Assessing a letter in an array element using a variable

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to get this program to get the first letter of one of the array elements using a number from a different string list. However, it is returning nothing.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set s=1234 1243 1324 1342 1432 1423 2134 2143 2314 2341 2431 2413 3214 3241 3124 3142         3412 3421 4231 4213 4321 4312 4132 4123
set num[1]=123
set num[2]=456
set num[3]=789
set num[4]=101
for %%a in (!s!) do (
set w=%%a
echo !w!
set fnum=!num[%w:~0,1%]!
echo !fnum!
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set s=1234 1243 1324 1342 1432 1423 2134 2143 2314 2341 2431 2413 3214 3241 3124 3142         3412 3421 4231 4213 4321 4312 4132 4123
set num[1]=123
set num[2]=456
set num[3]=789
set num[4]=101
for %%a in (!s!) do (
set w=%%a
echo !w!
for /f %%g in ("num[!w:~0,1!]") do set fnum=!%%g!
echo !fnum!
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set s=1234 1243 1324 1342 1432 1423 2134 2143 2314 2341 2431 2413 3214 3241 3124 3142 3412 3421 4231 4213 4321 4312 4132 4123
set num[1]=123
set num[2]=456
set num[3]=789
set num[4]=101
for %%a in (%s%) do (
set w=%%a
echo !w!
CALL set fnum=%%num[!w:~0,1!]%%
echo !fnum!
)
GOTO :EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set s=1234 1243 1324 1342 1432 1423  2134 2143 2314 2341 2431 2413  3214 3241 3124 3142 3412 3421  4231 4213 4321 4312 4132 4123
set num[1]=123
set num[2]=456
set num[3]=789
set num[4]=101
for %%a in (!s!) do (
   set w=%%a
   echo !w!
   for /F %%w in ("!w:~0,1!") do set fnum=!num[%%w]!
   echo !fnum!
)
```

[Arrays, linked lists and other data structures in cmd.exe (batch) script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990)